# Confused about pointers?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a response into a variable, and I can't figure out how to do it.

This doesn't work - screws up memory, but no protection errors:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    list[i] = 'a';
}
```

Same with this - memory screwed up:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    *(((int*)(list))+i) = 'a';
}
//I don't think this is a string issues as this doesn't help:
//*(((int*)(list))+20) = '\0';
```

This causes a bus error:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    *list[i] = 'a';
}
```

*This works as desired:*

```
*list = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

**P.S.** `list` is `char**`.

Comment: `char**` isn't a sequence of bytes, it's a pointer to a pointer to a `char`. Did you allocate any memory?

Comment: you allocated memory for this **list** variable, right?

Comment: How would I allocate memory so it is done like `*list = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";` does it?

Comment: Oh. `*list=malloc(20)` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, a pointer can be used to represent an array, and a single string is an array of `char`, or in other words, a `char *`. This means that a `char **` is an array of strings. So if you want to put characters into the first string (assuming that memory has already been allocated to it), you should use `list[0][i] = 'a';` in the first loop - i.e., put `'a'` into position `i` of the `0`th string.

Another way of interpreting a `char **` (which is the one I suspect is the one you're supposed to use) is that it is a pointer that points to a pointer that points to an array of `char`. In that case, you can use the "outer" pointer to modify what the inner pointer points to; this can be used to first allocate the string and then write to it:

```
*list = malloc(21); // Allocate 21 bytes and make the pointer that 'list' points to refer to that memory
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    (*list)[i] = 'a';
}
(*list)[20] = '\0'; // Also, you need the null terminator at the end of the string
```

In memory, this looks like this:

```
list ---> (another pointer) ---> |a|a|a|a|a|a|...|a|a|\0|
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want an array of bytes then `char**` is wrong – that's a pointer to a pointer to `char`. You want `char*` for an array, but if it's fixed length I'd declare it as `char list[20]`.

It seems like you want to write something like this:

```
char list[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    list[i] = 'a';
}
```

Or if you want heap allocation use

```
char *list = malloc(20);
```

---

Since we are reduced to guessing, I think that you meant to say that `*list` is an array of bytes.  In which case the code would be like so:

```
char **list = get_list_from_somewhere();
*list = malloc(20);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    *list[i] = 'a';
}
```

Comment: I can't. List is used by a MiG (mach ipc) subsystem. list is an address. I have to write to it so MiG picks the list and sends it.

Comment: @Nick Answering your question would be so much easier if you told us what your problem is. As your question stands, we have to guess. Not productive.

Comment: I can't let list be on the stack. It has to go on the heap.

Comment: @Nick before we go further you need to edit your question. The statements that list is `char**` and list is an array of bytes are not compatible. Please can you deal with that.

Comment: @Nick You still don't say what `list` is. Knowing its type isn't really enough. Anyway, I've had two guesses now and I'm going to move on to Portal 2!!

Comment: List is `serialized_t *list`. serialized_t is `typedef char* serialized_t`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char** list
```

Isn't a 'array of bytes' its a 'pointer to a pointer pointing to char' which you can think of as a 'list of lists of char'.  Also if you define it this way, you need to malloc enough memory to hold the data.

When you write:

```
list[i] = 'a';
```

Its messing up memory because your placing a char 'a' in a location specified to hold a pointer.  Actually in most compilers character literals are of type int so your actually storing an int form of 'a' as a pointer to a memory location which can cause all sorts of memory corruption.

If you want 'list' to be on the stack then define it as:

```
char list[20]
```

If you want 'list' to be in the heap then define it as:

```
char* list;
list = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
```

In either case access it as:

```
list[i]
```

Also its not safe to assume the size of int being equivalent to the size of a pointer as you to have done in your second example.  At least i think thats what you were trying to do.

Additionally if your storing raw bytes from a data stream or something of that sort you should likely be using 'unsigned char' not 'char' and for more safety use 'int8_t' as you can't always guarantee that 'char' is 8 bits although it is on the majority of platforms.

Answer (score 0):

How did you initialize your `list`?

```
char** list;
```

doesn't work in this case you'll have to have something like

```
char* list[20];
```

or dynamically allocated.